# Use Regex with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, regex, nspredicate

## Aim

- Using `NSPredicate` I would like to use Regex to match all strings beginning with "Test"
- I specifically want to use `Regex` and `NSPredicate`.

## Questions

1. What mistake am I making?
2. What is the right way to use Regex to achieve what I am trying to do.

## Code (My attempt, doesn't work)

```
let tests = ["Testhello", "Car", "a@b.com", "Test", "Test 123"]
let pattern = "^Test"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", pattern)

for test in tests {
    let eval = predicate.evaluate(with: test)
    print("\(test) - \(eval)")
}
```

## Output

```
Testhello - false
Car - false
a@b.com - false
Test - true
Test 123 - false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex used with `NSPRedicate` and `MATCHES` must match the whole string, so you need to use

```swift
let pattern = "Test.*"
```

Or - if there can be mutliple lines in the input string:

```swift
let pattern = "(?s)Test.*"
```

to let the `.*` consume the rest of the string.

If the string must end with `Test`, use

```swift
let pattern = "(?s).*Test"
```

You do not even need the `^` or `$` anchors here since they are implicit here.

If the string must *contain* a `Test` substring, use

```swift
let pattern = "(?s).*Test.*"
```

Note that this is not efficient though due to high backtracking caused by the first `.*`.

Comment: Thanks a ton!!, Pardon my ignorance, I was using https://regex101.com to test the regex. There `^Test` seem to match, however here you are matching with `^Test.*`. I am trying to build a UI which accepts the Regex and hence the question. I will accept the answer in 10 min, not allowing to accept it right away.

Comment: Or should I be adding `.*` to what ever the user inputs so that it applies to the entire string?

Comment: @user1046037 The point is that you must match the whole string. So, if the string starts with a `Test`, it must be `Test.*`. If it ends with `Test`, use `.*Test`. You do not even need the `^` here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for patiently clarifying my doubts!!

Answer (score 0):

You try an exact match.... try with MATCHES, try LIKE or CONTAINS instead.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS %@", pattern)
```

See [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789) as you need

Comment: I would like to use REGEX as the user would be inputting a REGEX, the example posted in my question is a simplified example.

Comment: Depends where you want to manage the uncertainty by user or by the program. Anyway both is valid