# NSPredicate SELF MATCHES doesn't work with simple contains regex

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

All I need is to check using `NSPredicate` and `evaluate` pattern if my string contains `.page.link` phrase.

```
extension String {
    func isValid(for string: String) -> Bool {
        NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", string).evaluate(with: self)
    }
}

let pattern = ".page.link" // "\\.page\\.link"

"joyone.page.link/abcd?title=abcd".isValid(for: pattern) //false
"joyone.page.link".isValid(for: pattern) //false
"joyone.nopage.link/abcd?title=abcd".isValid(for: pattern) //false
```

I know there is a simpler way to do this, but it is a part of something bigger, and my pattern is just case in enum.

First two should be `true`.

Comment: Doesn't `MATCHES` in `NSPredicate` takes the whole string?

Comment: Does it? Let me check...

Comment: Use `CONTAINS` maybe instead?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/75387666/1187415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCHES` considers always the whole string.

`range(of:options:)` can also talk `Regex` and is easier to use

```
extension String {
    func isValid(for pattern: String) -> Bool {
        range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course @vadian answer is very correct and it is recommended, but here the solution is the following:

```
let pattern = ".{1,}\\.page\\.link.{1,}"
```

Thanks for the comment that it considers a whole string.

Comment: You shouldn't need `^` nor `$`, since the `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES` implies them, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It doesnt require `^` nor `$`.